# Dynamically update S3 zip file for source lambda function in AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have a .NET application in GitHub that I am  trying to deploy using AWS CodePipeline.

In my repo, I have a buildspec.yml file which builds the application, then zips it up and stores it in S3...

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --channel STS
      
  build:
    commands:
      - dotnet restore
      - dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish aws-api/aws-api.csproj --self-contained false
      - cp deployment.yml ./publish

      # Create zip file of publish files
      - cd publish
      - zip -r publish.zip .

      # Copy the zip file to S3
      - aws s3 cp publish.zip s3://aws-api-packages/
      
artifacts:
  files:
    - publish/**/*
  
runtime: dotnetcore6.0
```

In the AWS CodePipeline GUI Console, I have set up a pipeline which takes the source code from my GitHub repo, runs CodeBuild which builds the build artifacts, and then deploys this to CloudFormation.

Below is my CloudFormation yml template file which builds the CloudFormation stack...

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running
  in Amazon Lambda.

Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'aws-api-packages'

  Key:
    Type: String
    Default: 'publish.zip'

Resources:
  AspNetCoreFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: aws-api
      Runtime: dotnet6
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Ref BucketName
        Key: !Ref Key
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 30
      Role: my-api-stack-role
      Events:
        ProxyResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: "/{proxy+}"
            Method: ANY
        RootResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: "/"
            Method: ANY
Outputs:
  ApiURL:
    Description: API endpoint URL for Prod environment
    Value:
      Fn::Sub: https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/
```

What I am finding is, because the zip file which gets created in S3 doesn't change it's name, the Lambda function isn't recognising this as being updated, so any changes to my application are not being recognised.

My question is how am I able to dynamically update the S3 file, and then also reference this in the CodeUri part of the CloudFormation template? Or is there a more best practice way to achieve this?

Comment: You will need to use "aws cloudformation package" command that will automatically replace your codeuri with the new artifact location and then you can use the output template of the above command in the next stage to deploy